# JsonLD+MongoDB: Store JsonLD in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, node-webkit, json-ld, database

I am creating a Desktop application using `Node-WebKit`. The application is basically to create documents (details of an employee's daily work), any registered user can comment on these documents. The documents that I am creating will be split into sections. The users will comment on particular sections. I want to link these sections with the comments that the users post. The linking will be done using `JsonLD`. I am using `MongoDB` to store the data.
I am using sails.js in backend and AngularJs in frontend.
Usually we store our objects in this way:

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
    document: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    comments: {
        collection: 'Comments',
        via: 'document'
    }
    project:{
        model: 'Project'
    }
  }
};
```

I have done some RnD on JsonLD and according to what I know about JsonLD. This is how the JsonLD will be:

```
{
 "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name",
    "depiction":
     {
  "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/depiction",
  "@type": "@id"
 },
    "homepage":
 {
    "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage",
    "@type": "@id"
 },
 }
}
```

I would like to know how I can store the `JsonLD` in `MongoDB`

Comment: There are lots of options here. Mostly what we are talking about is a REST API that will respect JSON objects. There are commercial services, but the BEST solution is usually served by "rolling your own" service to those requests on the server side. It all depends on how basic your CRUD requests will be for your application.

Comment: I am familiar with the crud operations. I just want to know how the json-ld can be stored. Can you please explain how it works? Storing of json objects are okay for me. But don't know how jsonld can be stored.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain your intent. Otherwise "too broad" is a standard close/hold reason I have to submit without a more specific intent.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please go through the same and help me solving the issue. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

JSON-LD is valid JSON, so you can store JSON-LD the same way you store JSON objects. What JSON-LD does is to map concepts to URLs but everything remains valid JSON and they look like regular JSON if the context property is used. You can find a good example in slides 22 - 23 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/lanthaler/building-next-generation-web-ap-is-with-jsonld-and-hydra/22). Also you may find "[JSON-LD and MongoDB](http://www.slideshare.net/gkellogg1/jsonld-and-mongodb)" presentation interesting.

I am doing the same thing in a Java backend using the MongoDB java client and I just treat JSON-LD objects as regular JSON objects.

Comment: Hi @Nandana, are you saving the context with the mongo document in the same collection, or are you storing the context in code/seperate collection?